# Route all traffic (except port 3336 and a few more) from eth0 to specific ip

Tags: networking, server, vpn, routing

How can I route all incoming traffic from eth0 interface to ip 10.8.0.5 (VPN tunnel)?

I need to forward incoming traffic except port 3666, to specific ip on ubuntu 22.04 machine.

In future list of ports that should not be routed will get bigger.

How can i do it the best way?

I have explained my situation here -> https://serverfault.com/questions/1130659/route-all-traffic-except-port-3336-and-a-few-more-from-eth0-to-specific-ip

and here -> https://serverfault.com/questions/1130369/proxy-all-requests-from-one-machine-to-another-using-nginx-or-anything-else

Thank you!

Comment: Answered this question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1130659/route-all-traffic-except-port-3336-and-a-few-more-from-eth0-to-specific-ip/1132381#1132381)